# MikroTik. NAT forwarding is not working for local network

Tags: mikrotik

I try to access my external IP address from the local network, but instead of reaching my webserver behind NAT - the webfig page shows up.

NAT forwarding is working when accessing from the internet.

EDIT: This is my current nat config

```
[admin@MikroTik] > ip firewall nat print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic
 0    ;;; defconf: masquerade
      chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface-list=WAN ipsec-policy=out,none

 1    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=<server's ip> to-ports=80 protocol=tcp in-interface=ether1 dst-port=80
```

Comment: Look up "Hairping NAT" on the documentation. It is not trivial to set up but that is what is missing - your traffic is not being NAT's because it is  bypassing the NAT.

Comment: Yup. That worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to use **Internal NAT Hairpin**. You can configure it in a few commands.

Let's assume that `1.1.1.1` is our external IP address, `192.168.1.0/24` is our local network, and `192.168.1.128` is a webserver.

Then, you need to add these **NAT** rules:

```
/ip firewall nat
# Forwarding
chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=1.1.1.1 dst-address=1.1.1.1 dst-port=80,443
chain=srcnat action=src-nat to-addresses=1.1.1.1 src-address=192.168.1.128 src-port=80,443

# Masquerading
hain=srcnat action=masquerade src-address=192.168.1.0/24 dst-address=192.168.1.0/24
```

This rule should already exist:

```
chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface-list=WAN
```

Comment: but what if my external IP address if dhcp controlled by provider and different from time to time? are there any tricks to avoid explicitly declaring dst-address ?

Comment: @xorza maybe by using destination-address-list and updating that with a script. Honestly, you'll need to use a Static IP for this reason.